# Using Protobuf-Net in an RPG

Tags: c#, wpf, protobuf-net

To make a long story short I am currently writing an RPG using WPF and C#.  I recently decided to implement(or try to at least) Protobuf-Net as the BinaryFormatter class just does not give the performance as Protobuf.

Basically, due to a severe lack of documentation I have been trying to put bits and pieces together that google has shown me.  My current problem is that I cannot get any inherited classes to serialize using a generic function.  I require this as the bulk of my work is an API so any new types that are created can be serialized.

An example of what I require,

```
    public sealed class SomeClass
{

    private RuntimeTypeModel protobuf = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();

    public T DeepCopy<T>(T template) where T : IsSomeBaseClass
    {
        Type templateType = template.GetType();
        this.protobuf.Add(templateType, true);

        // Get inherited classes.
        //
        //

        return (T)this.protobuf.DeepClone(template);
    }
}
```

Is this even possible with Protobuf-Net?  If someone could give me a push in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi; the *easiest* way to get inheritance working is with attributes. I've updated [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted) to show the inheritance attributes. Is using attributes an option? If so, you don't need to do *anything* here, other than *just use it* (you might find `Serializer.DeepClone<T>(template)` more convenient in your usage). I can happily add more info about configuring it via `RuntimeTypeModel`, but it needs more context; i.e. how do you propose to uniquely and robustly create a key for each derived type?

Comment: Hi Marc, attributes can be used for the classes that are in my API, the problem is since it is an API I need a generic public function so others may benefit from your speedy serializer.

Comment: this.protoBuf = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
            Type objType = obj.GetType();
            Type[] assemblyTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
            List<Type> templateTypes = new List<Type>(assemblyTypes.Where(item => item.IsClass && item.IsAssignableFrom(objType)).ToList());
            this.protoBuf.Add(objType, true);
            int key = 1000;
            foreach (Type t in templateTypes) { 
                protoBuf[objType].AddSubType(key, t);
                key += 1000;
            }

Comment: the key needs to be reliable and reproducible. GetTypes does not guarantee any order, especially if you add/remove/rename any types or change basically anything.